# Homedrive not mapping on 2 PCs

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, home-directory

I have a problem with 2 PCs. They are both on Windows 7 Professional SP1 64Bit and are part of a domain.

The problem:

Home drive (H:) not mapping to any user profile Admin / Non-Admin.

Facts:

- All other PCs are fully functional with all drives mapping and
  folders redirecting as expected.
- All other PCs are Windows 7 Professional SP1 32 Bit
- Everything else on the problematic PCs works. All other network
  drives map without any issues and folder redirection is working.
- Home drives are mapped through Active Directory Profile.
- All other drives are mapped through logon scripts.

Tried Solutions:

- Clearing Offline File Cache (Offline files are disabled but i used the Microsoft Fixit Tool anyway)
- removed all del commands from the logon scripts. Drives are no longer deleted upon login.
- Windows 7 fully updated

I am now stuck

Comment: The Home drives work for these users on other domain machines?

Can the users UNC to their H drives OK?

Comment: Difficult to say what's going on without the logon scripts. Perhaps, if the logon-scripts aren't 64bit compatible, they don't work. For example if they expect files in certain places and they are in `(x64)` or `SYSWOW64`. Also the machine could already have an `H:` but i expect you already checked that.

Comment: The Home Drives for the same users work on all other domain machines. The logon scripts are just a list of "net use" commands that map network shares and have no bit architecture specific paths. None of the logon scripts are using the H: drive so there is definitely no conflict.

Comment: try doing a net use H: /del  then a good ol' `gpupdate /force /boot` then reboot.

Might also then post a full gpresult from the user...
Also, desktops or laptops? Wireless fully off if laptop?

Comment: And with a logon script i think you can do a `pause` between the `net use` commands to see if there are error-messages.